# fetch and save the file posted by WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webclient

I have written a desktop application that posts a file to my website

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://mysite.com/getfile.aspx"),"POST", filename);
```

Now I need to create a page named getfile.aspx to save the posted Image. but I don't know how to access the posted file data.

I don't ask for code just need to know how to access the posted file.

Comment: I think it is `Request.Files` that you're looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            String imageURL = "xyz";
            String userName = "xyz";
            String password = "xyz";
            String destinationFolder = "xyz";
            Uri ftpSourceFilePath = new Uri(imageURL);

            if (ftpSourceFilePath.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
            {
                HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ftpSourceFilePath);
                NetworkCredential objCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                objRequest.Credentials = objCredential;
                objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
                int len = 0;
                int iProgressPercentage = 0;
                FileStream objFS = new FileStream((destinationFolder), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while ((len = objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {

                    objFS.Write(buffer, 0, len);

                }
            }
```